# How to count score of multiple-choice questions from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to count the number of right and wrong answers in a text file that contains 5 questions and 4 possible answers. As of right now i am able to loop through each question one at a time and the user is able to give an answer, however I can't seem to figure out how to count if an answer given by the user is right or wrong.

I know how to use an accumulator value in other simpler codes, however I just don't know how to format it when the questions are coming from a text file.

```
math_file = open("math.txt", 'r')
question_prompts = math_file.readlines()
count = 0
correct_answers = {"c":[0], "b":[1], "a":[2], "a":[3], "d":[4]}
startline = 0
for num in range(5):
    for i in range(startline, startline + 5):
        print(question_prompts[i])
    answer = input('Answer: ')
    startline = startline + 5
    if answer == correct_answers:
        count += 1
```

This code properly prints out the text file questions one at a time, for example, the first question is:
What is 4 x 6?

(a) 4

(b) 12

(c) 24

(d) 240

and then the program gives

Answer: (where the user can give input)

I tried to use a dictionary to put the answers of the questions in order of which they appear, but im not sure that is working. Any advice greatly appreciated!!

Comment: where are you using the dictionary? Nowhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The dictionary you trying to use should be other way round and the value in the dictionary should not be in a list.
- `if answer == correct_answers` is wrong since `"a" != {0:"c", 1:b, 2:"a", 3:"a", 4:"d"}`

  ```
  math_file = open("math.txt", 'r')
  question_prompts = math_file.readlines()
  count = 0
  correct_answers = {0:"c", 1:"b", 2:"a", 3:"a", 4:"d"}  # the line to change
  startline = 0
  for num in range(5):
      for i in range(startline, startline + 5):
          print(question_prompts[i])
      answer = input('Answer: ')
      startline = startline + 5
      if answer == correct_answers[num]: # the line to change
          count += 1
  ```

Comment: Some context: In general a dictionary should use the value you have as a key (the question number) and the value you want as the value (the answer).

The other line changes because you want to compare answer to the value of the dictionary for the corresponding question.

Also, since the dictionary keys are numbers, you could just use a list and access them by the index.

Comment: Thank you!! This is really helpful!!